# Issue with EdgeNGramFilterFactory filter class and multiple diactric character in a word

Tags: solr

I have indexed BLÅBÆRSOMMEREN into Solr and I have added EdgeNGramFilterFactory filter class like this:

```
<fieldType name="nGramtext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">     
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
```

Now, if I search with whole word: **BLÅBÆRSOMMEREN** it gives me result, but if I search with **BLÅB or BLÅBÆRSOMM** it does not give me result. Note I have perform edismax query on this field

As per the documentation [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) I guess, it should work with all these words but it does not.

> I have integrated Solr for an eCommerce Site. Initially I have
>   configure that word in Name field and it won't work. Then I have
>   configured that word in Short Description field only(Removed from
>   Name).

After this I have performed query and it works. Note: both fields have same field type.

```
 <field name="Name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="false" />  
 <field name="ShortDescription" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Moreover, there are copyfield like:

```
<copyfield source="Name" dest="nGramContent"/>
 <copyField source="ShortDescription" dest="nGramContent"/>
```

What I did wrong here? Please help! How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does the analysis page for your field say? Remember that the filters work in succession (and that the `side=""` parameter has been deprecated) and work with the value from the previous stage. Are you querying the correct field?

Comment: Initially I have tried without Side and it was not work. I have updated my question with my fieldtype

Comment: But how about the analysis under the solr admin? That's usually the best way to see which tokens are generated for both your query and the indexed value, and if they match. There's no need for two identical edgengrams, btw.

Comment: Do you need the PorterStemFilterFactory? a) PorterStemFilterFactory (afaik) is specific to English and that word is... Danish? (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.PorterStemFilterFactory) and b) you would be applying the porter stem filter on your ngrams here as the filters are chained?

Comment: @MatsLindh: I do not understand that analysis report in Solr Admin. How would I know whether they match or not(Query & Index word)?

Comment: If the same token is present on both sides, it's a match. They're usually colored with a bit different background for a match as well. And what @BunkerMentality says about the pporterstemfilter is correct - stemming and ngrams isn't a good match together, at least not with the stemming after the ngram and when having troubles getting a match. The query part of the field definition is also interesting when you're doing stemming.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Yes, I have reviewed it after. Query word is highlighted. But I found the another issue. If I configure same word in another field then it works fine. Note first and second field has same fieldtype. So, why it does not work before? Any suggestion?